# Processing huge File quickly in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a huge CSV file ~800 K records and using that data I have to form a POST request and make a rest call.
Initially I tried WITHOUT using threads but it is taking very long time to process it.

So I thought of using threads to speed up the process and followed below approach.

1. divided file into relatively smaller files (Tried with 3 files with approx ~5K data each file). (I Did this Manually Before passing to application)
2. Created 3 threads (traditional way by extending Thread class)
3. Reads each file with each thread and form HashMap with details required to form request and added it to ArrayList of POST Request
4. Send Post request to in loop
5. List item
6. Get the Response and add it to Response List

Both above approach takes too long to even complete half (>3 hrs). Might be one of them would not be good approach.

Could anyone please provide suggestion which helps me speeding up the process ? It is NOT mandatory to use threading.

Just to add that my code is at the consumer end and does not have much control on producer end.

**MultiThreadedFileRead (Main class that Extends Thread)**

```
class MultiThreadedFileRead extends Thread
{
        public static final String EMPTY = "";

        public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MultiThreadedFileRead.class);

        BufferedReader bReader = null;
        String filename = null;
        int Request_Num = 0;

        HashMap<Integer, String> filteredSrcDataMap = null;
        List<BrandRQ> brandRQList = null;
        List<BrandRS> brandRSList = null;

        ReadDLShipFile readDLShipFile = new ReadDLShipFile();
        GenerateAndProcessPostBrandAPI generateAndProcessPostBrandAPI = new GenerateAndProcessPostBrandAPI();


        MultiThreadedFileRead()
        {           
        }

        MultiThreadedFileRead(String fname) throws Exception
        {
            filename = fname;
            Request_Num = 0;
            List<BrandRQ> brandRQList = new ArrayList<BrandRQ>();
            List<BrandRS> brandRSList = new ArrayList<BrandRS>();
            this.start();
        }
        public void run()
        {

            logger.debug("File *** : " + this.filename);
            //Generate Source Data Map
            HashMap<Integer, String> filteredSrcDataMap = (HashMap<Integer, String>) readDLShipFile.readSourceFileData(this.filename);

            generateAndProcessPostBrandAPI.generateAndProcessPostRequest(filteredSrcDataMap, this);         

        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
        {

            String environment = ""; // TO BE UNCOMMENTED
            String outPutfileName = ""; // TO BE UNCOMMENTED
            BrandRetrivalProperties brProps = BrandRetrivalProperties.getInstance();

            if(args != null && args.length == 2 && DLPremiumUtil.isNotEmpty(args[0]) && DLPremiumUtil.isNotEmpty(args[1]))  // TO BE UNCOMMENTED
            {                                                   
                environment = args[0].trim();
                outPutfileName = args[1].trim();

                ApplicationInitializer applicationInitializer = new ApplicationInitializer(environment);
                applicationInitializer.initializeParams();


                logger.debug("Environment : " + environment);
                logger.debug("Filename : " + outPutfileName);   

            // TO BE UNCOMMENTED - START

            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid parameters passed. Expected paramenters: Environment");
                System.out.println("Sample Request: java -jar BrandRetrival.jar [prd|int] brand.dat");
                System.exit(1);
            }       

            MultiThreadedFileRead multiThreadedFileRead = new MultiThreadedFileRead();


            List<String> listOfFileNames = multiThreadedFileRead.getFileNames(brProps);
            logger.debug("List : " + listOfFileNames);

            int totalFileSize = listOfFileNames.size();
            logger.debug("totalFileSize : " + totalFileSize);

            MultiThreadedFileRead fr[]=new MultiThreadedFileRead[totalFileSize];
            logger.debug("Size of Array : " + fr.length);


            for(int i = 0; i < totalFileSize; i++)
            {               
                logger.debug("\nFile Getting Added to Array : " + brProps.getCountFilePath()+listOfFileNames.get(i));

                fr[i]=new MultiThreadedFileRead(brProps.getCountFilePath()+listOfFileNames.get(i));
            }

        }

        public List<String> getFileNames(BrandRetrivalProperties brProps)
        {

            MultiThreadedFileRead multiThreadedFileRead1 = new MultiThreadedFileRead();

            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";           
            String filename = multiThreadedFileRead1.getCounterFileName(brProps.getCountFilePath(), brProps.getCountFilePathStartsWith());

            List<String> fileNameList = null; 

            logger.debug("filename : " + filename);

            if(filename != null)
            {
                fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                try{

                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(brProps.getCountFilePath()+filename));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        fileNameList.add(line);
                    }                   

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block                  
                    e1.printStackTrace();               
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block                  ;
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block                  
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                } finally 
                {
                    if (br != null) 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            br.close();
                        } catch (IOException e4) 
                        {                           
                            e4.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e5) 
                        {                           
                            e5.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
            return fileNameList;
        }

        // Get the Name of the file which has name of individual CSV files to read to form the request
        public String getCounterFileName(String sourceFilePath, String sourceFileNameStartsWith)
        {           
            String fileName = null;

            if(sourceFilePath != null && !sourceFilePath.equals(EMPTY) && 
               sourceFileNameStartsWith != null && !sourceFileNameStartsWith.equals(EMPTY))
            {
                File filePath = new File(sourceFilePath);
                File[] listOfFiles = filePath.listFiles();

                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile() && listOfFiles[i].getName().startsWith(sourceFileNameStartsWith)) {
                    fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                    fileName = null;
                  }
                }
            }
            return fileName;
        }        
}
```

**GenerateAndProcessPostBrandAPI**

```
public class GenerateAndProcessPostBrandAPI {

    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GenerateAndProcessPostBrandAPI.class);

    List<BrandRQ> brandRQList = new ArrayList<BrandRQ>();
    List<BrandRS> brandRSList = new ArrayList<BrandRS>();

    DLPremiumClientPost dlPremiumclientPost = new DLPremiumClientPost();

    JSONRequestGenerator jsonRequestGenerator = new JSONRequestGenerator();


    public List<BrandRQ> getBrandRequstList(Map<Integer, String> filteredSrcDataMap)
    {
        if(filteredSrcDataMap != null)
        {
            brandRQList =  jsonRequestGenerator.getBrandRQList(filteredSrcDataMap, brandRQList);
        }
        return brandRQList;
    }

    public void generateAndProcessPostRequest(Map<Integer, String> filteredSrcDataMap, MultiThreadedFileRead multiThreadedFileRead)
    {
        if(filteredSrcDataMap != null)
        {
            brandRQList =  jsonRequestGenerator.getBrandRQList(filteredSrcDataMap, brandRQList);

            if(brandRQList != null && brandRQList.size() > 0)
            {

                BrandRetrivalProperties brProps = BrandRetrivalProperties.getInstance();
                String postBrandsEndpoint = brProps.getPostBrandsEndPoint();

                for (BrandRQ brandRQ : brandRQList)
                {
                    multiThreadedFileRead.Request_Num = multiThreadedFileRead.Request_Num + 1;
                    logger.debug("Brand Request - " + multiThreadedFileRead.Request_Num + " : " + ObjectToJSONCovertor.converToJSON(brandRQ));

                    BrandRS brandResponse = dlPremiumclientPost.loadBrandApiResponseJSON(brandRQ, postBrandsEndpoint, DLPremiumUtil.getTransactionID(), BrandConstants.AUTH_TOKEN);

                    logger.debug("Response - " + multiThreadedFileRead.Request_Num +  " : " + ObjectToJSONCovertor.converToJSON(brandResponse));

                    brandRSList.add(brandResponse);                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't format text as code, not unless you want to make your question hard to read.

Comment: Have you *profiled* the code?  You may be observing the symptom of slow read times, but have you actually put a profiler on your code to give you a better clue as to where to start?

Comment: Show your code. There must be something in your code that's bogging you down, not the processing of the file

Comment: So... you have started your question about processing large file in Java, yet you "by the way" mention that every row is transformed into HTTP POST request. Don't you feel like the bottleneck might be there instead of disk I/O :). And based on your info your requests might be as fast as 15ms (if 400k takes 4 hours in 3 threads) ... that is not that slow for a HTTP request.

Comment: Does your REST API have a bulk request implementation?
Sending every single Entry with one request each takes a lot of time.
SOLR and Elastic, for example, accept requests with 1000-2000 items per request. This speeds the process up ENORMOUSLY. If your API does not have this functionality, you should look into implementing it.

Comment: “Reads each file … and added it to ArrayList of POST Request”  Keeping a very large data set *in memory* is a good way to slow down your program.  Read a record, send the corresponding POST request, and then refrain from storing the record anywhere.  The entire process should consist of one loop.

Comment: After collaborative troubleshooting this, it was found that producer was not able to handle the load. Hence it was decided that Project team at Producer end will work on handling huge data as well as will be implementing Caching mechanism.

Thank you all your suggestion / help. This can be marked as CLOSED at this point.